# Getting routing data after redirect in angular service

Tags: angular

I am working on creating a dynamic breadcrumb data based on current route but i am facing an issue with getting the first route data after a redirect in service, i can only get it if i moved my code inside a component

here is the code:

app.routing:

```js
export const routes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: LayoutMainComponent,
    children: [
        {
        path: 'first',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'second',
            loadComponent: () =>
              import('....component'),
          },
          {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'first',
            pathMatch: 'prefix',
          },
        ],
      },

         {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'first/second',
        pathMatch: 'prefix',
      },
]
```

- breadcrumb Service: here is where i need to get the route after redirect after the user first accesses  the site:

  ```js
  // I have this observables which work fine once user start changing route but does not work with first load
    breadcrumbMenuItems$: Observable<MenuItem[]> = this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((event): event is NavigationEnd => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map((event: NavigationEnd) => {
        const url = event.urlAfterRedirects || this.router.url;
        return this.generateBreadcrumbs(url);
      }),
      startWith(this._fetchInitialBreadcrumbs()),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      catchError((error: any) => {
        console.error(this.errorMessage, error);
        return of([]);
      })
    );
  ```

now what i tried for getting the route after redirect `/first/second` is the following

```js
 constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private readonly location: Location
  ) {
    console.log('========= ROUTER ===========');
    console.log('ROUTER::', this.router);
    console.log( 'ROUTER: routerState.snapshot-URL:',
      this.router.routerState.snapshot.url );
    console.log('this.router.url:', this.router.url);

    console.log(' =============== ACTIVATED ROUTE ===============');
    console.log('activatedRoute.pathFromRoot:',
      this.activatedRoute.pathFromRoot );
    console.log( 'activatedRoute.snapshot.url:',
      this.activatedRoute.snapshot );

    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe((params) => {
      console.log(
        'params:', params );

     console.log( 'params.next:', params['next'] );
    });

    console.log( 'routeConfig',
      this.activatedRoute.routeConfig?.path?.split('?')[0] );

    console.log(' ========== Angular LOCATION ===========');
    console.log('location:: ', this.location.path());

    console.log(' =============== window ===============');
    console.log('windowURL:' , window.location.href);
    console.log('windowPath:' , window.location.pathname);

}
```

now all of the above either give me '/' empty init path before the redirect or undefined

and there one wired result:
inside this log: `console.log('ROUTER::', this.router);`

the `routerState.snapshot.url` is exactly what i need

but the log of `this.router.routerState.snapshot.url );` just give me '/'

**EDIT**: i forget to mention that i do not want to subscribe inside the service since I am using a declarative reactive Rxjs approach and i combine breadcrumbMenuItems$ with some other layout observables to create layout vm$ and subscribe there only once using async

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe directly to the router events and filter out the NavigationEnd:

```
this.router.events.pipe(
        map((event) => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                return event;
            }
        }
    ).subscribe((event) => {
            const url = event.urlAfterRedirects;
    });
```

https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationEnd

Comment: i know and it will work, but i do not want to subscribe since i am using a declarative rxjs approach and i combine breadcrumbMenuItems$ with some other layout observables to create layout vm$ and subscribe there only once using async